# roots of a polynomial with zero coefficient summation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Consider a polynomial, for which the summation of the coefficients is zero.What do we know about its roots?

Comment: $x^2 - 3x + 2$ has the roots $x=1$ and $x=2$, so the statement is not true. Or did I misunderstand the question? – The sum of the coefficients is zero exactly if $x=1$ is a root, all other roots can be arbitrary real (or complex) numbers.

Comment: to which statement are you referring, please?

Comment: @Martin R: I see now the question has been edited. Don't answer my comment.

Answer (score 3):

If the coeffients of a polynomial $p(x)=\sum p_ix^i$ sum to zero, then
$$p(1)=\sum p_i1^i=\sum p_i=0,$$
so $1$ is a root of $p$.